# React Material Selects Not Showing Value After Selected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am looking to finish a language software I am working on. Unfortunately, I consistently have problems with the react material ui select components. I just can't seem to get them to work in general. In the below example I have the selected value doesn't show in the UI.

JSX

```
<FormControl>
  <InputLabel htmlFor="nativeLanguageSelect">Select Language You Already Know</InputLabel>
  <Select
    onChange={ this.nativeLanguageChange }
    inputProps={{
      name: 'nativeLanguage',
      id: 'nativeLanguageSelect'
    }}
    value={ this.state.nativeLanguageDescription }
  >
    { Object.entries(languagesKey()).map(([key, value], index) => {
        if (key != this.state.nativeLanguage && key != 'bg') {
          const countryCode = key == 'ja' ? 'jp' : key,
                img = require(`../../assets/flags/flag-${countryCode.toUpperCase()}.png`),
                bgImgSrc = `url(${img})`;

          return (
            <MenuItem className="listItemFlag" key={ index } value={ key } style={{ backgroundImage: bgImgSrc }}>{ value }</MenuItem>
          )
        }
      })
    }
  </Select>
</FormControl>
```

Handler

```
nativeLanguageChange = (e) => {
  this.setState({
    nativeLanguage: e.target.value,
    nativeLanguageDescription: languagesKey()[e.target.value]
  })
}
```

State

```
this.state = {
  description:               null,
  language:                  '',
  langaugeDescription:       '',
  listName:                  null,
  listIdToDelete:            null,
  nativeLanguage:            '',
  nativeLanguageDescription: '',
  openModal:                 false,
  words:                     null
}
```

Comment: Also, I logged out state and it is correctly updating.

Comment: `MenuItem` value is the `key`, is this intentional ?

Comment: Just to clear things up, its only the nativeLanguageDescription that doesnt apppear right?

Comment: Yes Correct so the key is actually a language code and I use that to make API requests with. The UI display uses the language code to display the languageDescription which is the human read version so en becomes English etc...

Yes... just nativeLanguageDescription is not appearing thus keeping the select visually empty despite the state updating...

Comment: `<Select />` value (which is: `nativeLanguageDescription`) must match on the items values, but the items values are keys, I think you need to change `Select` value to `this.state. nativeLanguage `

Comment: Why do I have to have them matching... why can I not set the value in state myself after taking the key passing it through a function and setting state.

Comment: `Select` determines which `MenuItem` to show as selected based on [matching the value](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.5.0/packages/material-ui/src/Select/SelectInput.js#L227) of the `Select` to the value of the `MenuItem`.

Comment: Wow, that sounds like a hardline no way around that bit Ryan. I suppose I'll have to devise another way to setup my keycodes and menus. Thank you for letting me know it simply cannot be done how I thought!

Comment: So I changed my local code so that the menuitem value and the value from state are the same. It still doesn't work. I'm thinking I will need to stop using material ui because it doens't make sense to me that I can't set it to a contradicting value and when I set it to a matching value it still doesn't work. Have you used ant-d framework? How are the selects in that one?